# Random Color Generator (full section, not just a single word)

Tags: jquery, html

I found a jQuery random color function somewhere on stackoverflow, but I need to tweak this so that whatever element has the class added to it, that whole part will be the same color instead of every word being a random color.

```js
// any valid css colours
var colors = ["#FF0000", "#FFC0CB", "#C71585", "#FFA500", "#FF4500", "#FFFF00", "#800080", "#4B0082", "#00FF00", "#2E8B57", "#808000", "#008080", "#00FFFF", "#0000FF", "#DAA520", "#800000", "#00BFFF"];

 $('.colortxt').html(function (i, text) {
  return $.map(text.split(' '), function (word) {
    return '<span style="color:'
     + colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]
     + '">' + word + '</span>';
  }).join(' ');
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="colortxt"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `map` method that splits string into words and apllies changing color function to every word

```js
// any valid css colours
var colors = ["#FF0000", "#FFC0CB", "#C71585", "#FFA500", "#FF4500", "#FFFF00", "#800080", "#4B0082", "#00FF00", "#2E8B57", "#808000", "#008080", "#00FFFF", "#0000FF", "#DAA520", "#800000", "#00BFFF"];

 $('.colortxt').html(function (i, text) {
  return '<p style="color:'
     + colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]
     + '">' + text + '</p>';
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="colortxt"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</h1>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!